# Android Studio - How to switch and stay in new activity

Tags: android

I have the following  situation

-I have 3 activities: "Splash screen", "Main" and "WifiScan" with the order:

Splash Screen(for 10 sec)---> Main.

I want to switch with button on "Wifiscan" activity from "Main" activity, and  I want to stay here until I finish the activity.

My problem is that, when I switch to "Wifiscan" with an intent action by button , the activity "Wifiscan" 
 is closed automatically after few seconds by the "Main" activity and I can't do anything in activity 'Wifiscan".

Can you help me 'to stay' in "Wifiscan"  activity, to finish this activity and after that to come back to "Main" activty?

Comment: What do you mean "the activity "Wifiscan" is closed automatically after few seconds"? That's not default behavior, it must be something you do.

Comment: Could you add the code of both your main and wifiscan activity?